# jqplot and width

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am having some trouble with the width of the ticks on the xaxis. It seems that they are auto adjusted to fill the width of the div - what if I want to override that?

Regards,

Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but could not find anything useful in the docs. I solved it by changing the width of the div dynamically, based on the data array size, before drawing the graph.

Comment: #devk: could you please post your solution ? i am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Ticks option for the x axis and give it an array of values you want to put in yours. it solve my problem.